# Cannot to download a file using wget

Tags: macos, wget

I cannot to download a file using wget, but if I put this link to Safari it downloads successfully. What the reason of that problem?

```
Andreys-MacBook-Pro:currentFolder kleverigheid$ wget http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25.pl?file=gfs.t06z.pgrb2.0p25.f000&all_lev=on&all_var=on&subregion=&leftlon=22&rightlon=42&toplat=53&bottomlat=45&dir=/gfs.2015070506
[1] 70728
[2] 70729
[3] 70730
[4] 70731
[5] 70732
[6] 70733
[7] 70734
[2]   Done                    all_lev=on
[3]   Done                    all_var=on
[4]   Done                    subregion=
[5]   Done                    leftlon=22
[6]-  Done                    rightlon=42
[7]+  Done                    toplat=53
Andreys-MacBook-Pro:currentFolder kleverigheid$ --2015-07-05 15:02:05--  http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25.pl?file=gfs.t06z.pgrb2.0p25.f000
Resolving nomads.ncep.noaa.gov... 140.90.101.62
Connecting to nomads.ncep.noaa.gov|140.90.101.62|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 data file not present
2015-07-05 15:02:06 ERROR 404: data file not present.

Andreys-MacBook-Pro:currentFolder kleverigheid$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell - not wget - interprets `&` as a special character, instructing to run a program in the background. To avoid that, simply put the whole URL in quotes, like this:

```
$ wget 'http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25.pl?file=gfs.t06z.pgrb2.0p25.f000&all_lev=on&all_var=on&subregion=&leftlon=22&rightlon=42&toplat=53&bottomlat=45&dir=/gfs.2015070506'
```